# Unfolding the asterisk (`*`) in comand line

Tags: command-line, wildcards

I was doing a group command (moving files) and something unfolded the asterisk (I think I clicked some key, and didn't notice) What happened was that:

```
mv *
```

turned into:

```
mv file1 file2 file3 dir1 dir2 dir3
```

This seems really usefull to me, since I could just remove the folders I didn't want to move, and move everything into one of the directories.

How do I unfold the asterisk again?

I have not been able to (through google or this site) to find out how to to this ;-) Thanks for the help

Comment: bash @don_crissti the emulater should be gnomes terminal emulater

Comment: definite duplicate of that @don_crissti Didn't find that in my search. I have flagged myself. Thanks for the help ;-)